# Detect printable keys

Tags: javascript, keyboard

I need to detect whether the key which has just been pressed is a printable key, like a character, possibly accented, a number, a space, a punctuation symbol and so on, or a non printable key, like ENTER, TAB or DELETE.

Is there a reliable way to do this in Javascript, other than listing all non printable keys and hope not to forget some?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179708/how-to-detect-if-the-pressed-key-will-produce-a-character-inside-an-input-text/4180715#4180715) yesterday. Note that you have to use the `keypress` event for anything character-related; `keydown` won't do.

I would argue that <kbd>Enter</kbd> is printable, by the way, and this function considers it to be. If you disagree, you can amend it to filter out keypresses with the `which` or `keyCode` property of the event set to 13.

```
function isCharacterKeyPress(evt) {
    if (typeof evt.which == "undefined") {
        // This is IE, which only fires keypress events for printable keys
        return true;
    } else if (typeof evt.which == "number" && evt.which > 0) {
        // In other browsers except old versions of WebKit, evt.which is
        // only greater than zero if the keypress is a printable key.
        // We need to filter out backspace and ctrl/alt/meta key combinations
        return !evt.ctrlKey && !evt.metaKey && !evt.altKey && evt.which != 8;
    }
    return false;
}

var input = document.getElementById("your_input_id");
input.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;

    if (isCharacterKeyPress(evt)) {
        // Do your stuff here
        alert("Character!");
    }
});
```

Comment: MDN suggests that we should not use the `window.event` property because it is non standard and there may be incompatibilities, [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) .  Any opinions on that ?

Comment: @Segmentation: I absolutely agree. I'd only ever use it for compatibility with IE <= 8, which was more of a concern in 2010 than it is now. `window.event` will only be used in old IE in this answer anyway because the event object will be passed into the event handler in all modern browsers.

Comment: The `keypress` event is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event

Comment: The `which` event is deprecated too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which

Answer (score 37):

Luckily, this task is much easier in modern browsers. You can now use [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) to detect a printable key via its length.

```js
test.onkeydown = e => {
  let isPrintableKey = e.key.length === 1;
  alert(`Key '${e.key}' is printable: ${isPrintableKey}`);
}
```

```html
<input id="test">
```

Besides that, you can also detect any other keys from the list, like `Enter`, `Delete`, `Backspace`, `Tab`, etc.

This method is much more reliable simply because unlike `event.which`, `event.key` is already standardized.

Comment: It should be noted that this will crash ungracefully in older browsers, because `e.key` is undefined. It's safer to check `e.key && e.key.length === 1`. Even anno 2018, global support for `key` is only ~80%: https://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't that reliable. In IE11 for example you will get 
"Divide", "Multiply", "Subtract", "Add", "Decimal"
if you press the math operator key or comma on the numpad.

Comment: Be careful if you're using this with `e.preventDefault()` because you'll also block keyboard shortcuts (CMD+R, for example).

Comment: Is is actually defined that events for printable keys will always have a “key-length” of 1? I could imagine that some keys in some languages will result in more then one character.

Comment: This simply won't work in so many cases that this just should not be the most upvoted answer

Answer (score 2):

If you need to identify printable key just for change detection as user change the input, you could use [`oninput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput) event.

Answer (score 2):

```
let isPrintableKey = event.key.length === 1 || event.key === 'Unidentified';
```

If you do not include: `|| event.key === 'Unidentified'` your code will not work on mobile browsers.