# Js key restriction but with a little mercy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I build a mechnism using JS for accepting only digits :

However I want to allow  : 
<kbd>Delete</kbd>, <kbd>Backspace</kbd> , <kbd>left arrow</kbd> , <kbd>right arrow</kbd> :

the solution I came up with is :

assuming I write in html *(which I know its bad to send event , but lets focus on the Js code please)* :

```
<input  onKeyPress='return CheckDigit(event)'/>



function CheckDigit(evt)
{
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (((charCode >= 48) && (charCode <= 57)) || checkIfDelOrNavigate(charCode)))
        return true;
    return false;
}

  function checkIfDelOrNavigate(c)
    {
        if (((c == 46) || (c == 39) || (c == 37) || (c == 8))) return true;return false;
        /*46=delete , 39,37 = arrows , 8=backspace*/
    }
```

Questions :

- Is it the right solution ? (and if it ain't , can you please supply an answer)
- I assume it can be changed to regex checking :

code:

```
 var regEx =/^[0-9]+$/;    
 isValid = regEx.test(keyChar); 
 return isValid;
```

But what will be the full `regEx` expression ?

*p.s. : 
Strange but all the solutions I saw doesnt want to allow the <kbd>Delete</kbd>, <kbd>Backspace</kbd> , <kbd>left arrow</kbd> , <kbd>right arrow</kbd>  chars , just the category itself.*

Comment: The keypress does not even fire for those keys, at least in chrome. So it's pretty simple, you have to ignore those keys for cross browser consistency.

Comment: Hi @Esailija yeah but in FF it does Fire http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html

Comment: Also, test if the user can Ctrl+A/Z/X/C/V Tab F5 Enter and screenshot. I hate being stuck in one input box where these doesn't work, hence I took a different approach last time.

Comment: Here's what I did yesterday when I needed a numbers-only input, it also removes unnecessary leading zeroes on blur (`change`), check if it's of any use http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/Va6Qb/ (the ugly hack on Chrome is because changing the selectionStart/End doesn't work properly in the `input` event, and the hack for IE is because it doesn't fire the `input` event when characters are deleted).

Comment: For newer browsers, `<input type="number">` may suffice.

Comment: You might find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194163/detect-printable-keys) useful.

Comment: Isn't it easier to clear the input immediately after keypress leaving only allowed characters(numbers in this case)?

Comment: Not if you want to preserve the text cursor location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I combine the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194163/detect-printable-keys) with the following check to make sure I only capture digits while allowing for non-printable characters. You'll have to do something about the paste operation, though.

```
return !window.isNaN(String.fromCharCode(event.which))
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F6YMf/3/).

Comment: It still allows white space to be inserted, but nice answer. Just needs a `event.which !== 32` somewhere in there. Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/F6YMf/4/).