# jQuery check if pressed key is printable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

By using jQuery `keydown` i'm able to get the target and pressed `keyCode`

I wanted to check it the pressing key is PRINTABLE KEY

So I used `e.key`, but this doesn't work in all browsers

Results for `e.key`:

```
Mozilla FireFox : MozPrintableKey
Google Chome: undefined
IE: undefined
```

Is there a all browser compatible way to check if pressing key is printable?

Comment: you can use the keypress event... it is fired if a printanble character is pressed

Comment: Note that a "pressed key" may be printable sometimes and not others. E.g., "V" is printable, but ctrl-V is paste which may or may not add printable characters depending on what the clipboard contains at the time.

Comment: @ArunPJohny but keypress will not detect non printable keys like tab, control etc..

Comment: Now what is "printable"? Different fonts have different characters that able to be rendered and printed.

Comment: Is this link helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194163/detect-printable-keys

Answer (score 0):

You can define a printable key hash list,if you want it work in all browsers

```
var printableTable = {
  65:a,
  66:b,
  67:c
  ....
}
var el = document.getElementById("id");
el.onkeypress = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var keyCode = e.keyCode||e.which;
    if (keyCode in printableTable) {
        alert('this is printableTable!')
    }
});
```