# Determine if key press resulted in printable Unicode character being input without deprecated APIs

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

- [`char` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#Properties)
- [`charCode` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode)
- [`key` fires for both printable characters and control keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)
- [`keyCode` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)
- [`which` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which)
- [`keypress` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress)
- [`input` does not fire for elements that are not `input`, `textarea`, `select` or `contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) - most annoyingly `tabindex` is not enough

Is the recommended way going forwards to keep the list of [predefined `key` values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values) as a blacklist and assume what's not on there is a printable character? How's that going to work out for keyboards with special/programmable keys?

When trying to capture printable characters on non-`input|textarea|select|contenteditable`, is as of current the only non-hacky (no incomplete ranges or blacklists as seen in many similar questions) way without using deprecated features to use a hidden `input`/`textarea` and use its value for capturing characters that actually change that value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay after looking into it for some time, the answer is: You can't determine this without relying on deprecated APIs or `textarea` hack.

Of course these are unlikely to ever go away, but if someone ends up looking for a way to do this without them, they won't find one.

A partial solution is a blacklist of the `key` values, but it's only a question of a new TV coming out with a quirky remote with extra proprietary keys or something like that and all bets are off.

Answer (score 3):

As a pragmatic solution use `key`:

- assume that all single-character key names are printable

  - currently true except for space: `" "`
  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values
- check that no modifiers were pressed (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4194212)

Example code:

```
const isPrintableChar = e.key.length === 1 && e.key !== ' ';
const noModifier = !e.ctrlKey && !e.metaKey && !e.altKey;
return isPrintableChar && !noModifier;
```

For backward compatibility, consider using `e.which` as a fallback.

Comment: Just checked, this does not work with emojis correctly. I'm keeping a blacklist generated based on the MDN page for now.

Comment: +1 to the comment above. If the printable char is a Unicode astral (see https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode ) then length > 1 but it should still print. Since a blacklist is bound to get outdated, seems like the best solution is using the old deprecated APIs.