# Using querySelector to get each letter a user inputs

Tags: javascript, arrays

Trying to make a web page that will get each letter a user inputs and output it in a phonetic alphabet. For example (user types: Hello)(Output: Hotel , Echo , Lima, Lima, Oscar). This is what I have so far just need some guidance on how to get the value of each letter and compare it to like an Array to get the output.

```
//define UI variables
const userInput = document.querySelector('#input');
const phoneticAlphabet = ["Alpha"," Bravo","Charlie"];

//load all event listeners
loadEventListeners();

function loadEventListeners() {
  //add submit event 
  form.addEventListener('submit', submitInput);
}

//submit user input
function submitInput(e) {

  console.log(userInput.value);
  if (userInput.value === '') {
    alert('Add Input');
  } 
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that you would like to replace non-convertible characters from the input. For the same, I am using regular expression. I have also added the response in a "p" tag. And the code runs on clicking "Submit".

**Update:**
Extended my array for all alphabets :)

**Update 2:**
Thanks @CharlieBatista for pointing out. Now, the input accepts uppercase characters as well.

```js
//define UI variables
const form = document.phoneticForm;
const userInput = document.querySelector('#input');
const output = document.querySelector('#output');
const phoneticAlphabet = ['Alpha','Bravo','Charlie','Delta','Echo','Foxtrot','Golf','Hotel','India','Juliet','Kilo','Lima','Mike','November','Oscar','Papa','Quebec','Romeo','Sierra','Tango','Uniform','Victor','Whiskey','X-ray','Yankee','Zulu'];

//load all event listeners
loadEventListeners();

function loadEventListeners() {

  //add submit event 
  form.addEventListener('submit', submitInput);

}

//submit user input
function submitInput(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  var value = userInput.value;
  
  if (value === '') {
      alert('Add Input');
  } else {
   value = value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/gi,'');
    userInput.value = value;
    value = value.toLowerCase();
    var outputArr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < value.length; i++){
     outputArr.push(phoneticAlphabet[value.charCodeAt(i)-97]);
    }
    
    output.innerHTML = outputArr.join(', ');
  }

}
```

```html
<form name="phoneticForm">
  <input type="text" id="input">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Do you know why it does not accept upper case letters? Thanks for your help

Comment: @CharlieBatista I am guessing the index using the "keycode" by subtracting 97. So, for uniformity in my process, I decided to convert string into lowercase. Other approach would be to add a check first if the character is lower case or uppercase, and subtract 65 (for uppercase) or 97 (for lowercase).

Comment: @CharlieBatista you were right. There was a bug. I have updated my answer. Please check it out.

Comment: Thank you appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `key` property on the `keydown` event of the field to get the character that was pressed.

Then check if the key is a printable key using `key.length === 1` ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38802011/9325419)).

If the key is printable, convert it to uppercase, then to its character code using [String.prototype.charCodeAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) and then subtract 65 from it (character `A`). This will give you the index in your array.

If this index is within the bounds of the array, access the array and print the character.

```js
const phoneticAlphabet = ['Alpha','Bravo','Charlie','Delta','Echo','Foxtrot','Golf','Hotel','India','Juliet','Kilo','Lima','Mike','November','Oscar','Papa','Quebec','Romeo','Sierra','Tango','Uniform','Victor','Whiskey','X-ray','Yankee','Zulu'];

document.querySelector('#input').addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  const isPrintable = e.key.length === 1;
  console.clear();
  if (isPrintable) {
    const idx = e.key.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0) - 65;
    if (idx >= 0 && idx < phoneticAlphabet.length) {
      const phoneme = phoneticAlphabet[idx];
      console.log(phoneme);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
```