# KeyTyped event - not able to read the last char of a string

Tags: java, string, awt, keylistener

So I've been working on this password strength checker, and to provide visual feedback of the breakdown of points to the user as the password is being typed in, I use a KeyTyped event and then analyze the string and eventually start giving out points as the minimum length is reached. Here's what the a part of the analysis looks like :

```
if (in.matches("[a-z]+")){
    lowerPenalty = -15;
}
if (in.matches("[0-9]+")){
    numPenalty = -15;
}

for(int i=0;i<inLen;i++){
    if ((in.charAt(i) + "").matches("[A-Z]")){   
        upperCounter++;
        upperBonus = upperBonus + 4; 
    }
```

However, when I run the program, it doesn't consider the last character of the password typed in by the user, and thus the corresponding counter is not incremented. Here's the screenshot:

[image]

**As you can see in the above screenshot, the numCounter in Number Bonus row is still at '1' instead of '2'**. I've tried using KeyPressed event, though the problem still persists.

Please help.

As requested, here's the keyListener code:

```
input.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e1){

            if ((int)e1.getKeyChar() == 8){
                count = -1;
                baseScore = 0;
                lenBonus = 0;
                upperBonus = 0;
                upperCounter = 0;
                numBonus = 0;
                numCounter = 0;
                symBonus = 0;
                symCounter = 0;
                comBonus = 0;
                lowerPenalty = 0;
                numPenalty = 0;
                comBonus = 0;
                totalScore = 0;
                input.setText("");
                strength_lbl.setText("Enter a random password");
                strength_lbl.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

            }

            count++;
            Counter.setText(count+"");
            analyzeStr(input.getText());

            baseScore_txt.setText(baseScore+""  );
            lowerPen_txt.setText(lowerPenalty+"");
            numonlyPen_txt.setText(numPenalty+"");
            upperBonus_txt.setText(upperBonus+" [" + (upperCounter) + "x4]");
            numBonus_txt.setText(numBonus+" [" + numCounter + "x5]");
            symBonus_txt.setText(symBonus+" [" + symCounter + "x5]");
            comBonus_txt.setText(comBonus+"");
            totalScore = baseScore + lenBonus + upperBonus + numBonus + symBonus + comBonus + lowerPenalty + numPenalty;
            totalScore_txt.setText(totalScore+"");  

            if (totalScore>=1 && totalScore<50){
                strength_lbl.setText("Weak!");
                strength_lbl.setBackground(Color.red);
            }
            if (totalScore>=50 && totalScore<75){
                strength_lbl.setText("Average!");
                strength_lbl.setBackground(Color.orange);
            }
            if (totalScore>=75 && totalScore<100    ){
                strength_lbl.setText("Strong!");
                strength_lbl.setBackground(Color.cyan);
            }
            if (totalScore>=100){
                strength_lbl.setText("Secure!");
                strength_lbl.setBackground(Color.green);
            }


        }
    });
```

As requested, here's the analyzeString method:

```
    public void analyzeStr(String str){

    String in = input.getText();
    int inLen = input.getText().length();

    if (count == 1){
        strength_lbl.setBackground(Color.RED);
        strength_lbl.setText("At least 8 characters please!");
    }

    if  (input.getText().length()<8){
        lengthBonus_txt.setText("0");
    }
    else{
        lengthBonus_txt.setText(lenBonus +" [" + (count-8) + "x3]");
    }

    if (count==8){

        baseScore = 50;


        if (in.matches("[a-z]+")){
            lowerPenalty = -15;
        }

        if (in.matches("[0-9]+")){
            numPenalty = -15;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<inLen;i++){
            if ((in.charAt(i) + "").matches("[A-Z]")){
                upperCounter++;
                upperBonus = upperBonus + 4; 
            }

            if ((in.charAt(i) + "").matches("[0-9]")){
                numCounter++;
                numBonus = numBonus + 5;
            }

            if ((in.charAt(i) + "").matches("[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~]")){
                symCounter++;
                symBonus = symBonus + 5;
            }

        }

    }

    if (count>8){
        lenBonus = lenBonus + 3;
        lengthBonus_txt.setText(lenBonus+" [" + (inLen-7) + "x3]");

        if ((in.charAt(inLen-1) + "").matches("[A-Z]")){
            upperCounter++;
            upperBonus = upperBonus + 4; 
        }

        if ((in.charAt(inLen-1) + "").matches("[0-9]")){
            numCounter++;
            numBonus = numBonus + 5;
        }   

        if ((in.charAt(inLen-1) + "").matches("[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~]")){
            symCounter++;
            symBonus = symBonus + 5;
        }
    }

    if (count>=8){
        if (in.matches("[A-Z][0-9][!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~]")){
            comBonus = 25;
        }
        if (in.matches("[0-9][A-Z][!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~]")){
            comBonus = 25;
        }
        if (in.matches("[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~][0-9][A-Z]")){
            comBonus = 25;
        }
        if (in.matches("[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~][A-Z][0-9]")){
            comBonus = 25;
        }
        if (in.matches("[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~][A-Z][0-9]")){
            comBonus = 25;
        }
        if (in.matches("[A-Z][!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~][0-9]")){
            comBonus = 25;
        }
        if (in.matches("[0-9][!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~][A-Z]")){
            comBonus = 25;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: please post your KeyListener

Comment: Where are you setting `inLen`?

Comment: @JonSkeet, in my analyzeString method. Here it is: int inLen = input.getText().length();

Comment: It would help if you could provide a short piece of compilable code which illustrates the problem. (see sscce.org)

Comment: It seems that we will need the entire `analyzeString`

Comment: Ideally, just come up with a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. It shouldn't even need to have a UI, to be honest. But there's no point in us having to ask for more and more information, a bit at a time.

Comment: I would recommend you to use Character.isDigit, Character.isUpperCase, etc instead of most of those regexes. You get a more reliable, a more readable and possibly even a more correct solution.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I'm sorry for that, here's the jar file which clearly portrays the problem: http://www13.zippyshare.com/v/69720042/file.html

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener. There are ways to enter text in a text field without using the keyboard. Use a DocumentListener.

Comment: To ask 2 obvious questions, what happens if you run the for loop/loops until inLen+1? Have you printed out the characters it *does* read to check they are what you expect?

Comment: @bluesh34, OutOfBoundsException. That was the first thing I tried : )

Comment: What about question 2? +1 for info.

Comment: @kviiri, getting the same error even with those functions.

Comment: Please re-read Jon Skeet's last post. He's not asking for the complete program, but rather a new program, one that is *short but complete*, that demonstrates the problem. Else we'd drown in a ton of unrelated code.

Comment: @bluesh34, so it starts printing after the second char has been typed in. Here's the screen shot: http://speedcap.net/sharing/screen.php?id=files/55/e0/55e0a90496f3ba13152cc124c6749d27.png

Comment: Why doesn't it start printing after the 1st char is typed?

Comment: @bluesh34, I have no idea. It starts incrementing the lengthCounter from the first char, but prints from the second char.

Comment: @EnTHuSiAsTx94, yes, I wasn't actually thinking that a faulty regex was causing the problem. I just wanted to let you know about these methods since they are more concise, more readable and more reliable. isUpperCase is also better than [A-Z] because it also recognizes uppercase characters beyond A-Z, such as scandics.

Comment: Which classes are the code stubs posted in?

Comment: @kviiri, oh, thanks for your help. I actually managed to fix the problem using KeyPressed event instead. However, now all key presses are detected even though they don't print anything. Any idea how to fix this i.e. restrict the key presses to only printable characters?

Comment: Maybe this will help with the printable characters only: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179708/how-to-detect-if-the-pressed-key-will-produce-a-character-inside-an-input-text

Comment: `KeyListener` isn't really your best choice here, `DocumentListener` would be a better choice, but without a runnable example, it's very hard to decipher what's going on...