# Validate key input in field with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation

I am using

```
document.getElementById('input-field').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  if (!String.fromCharCode(e.which).match(/[A-Za-z0-9,]/)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

It almost works. The problem is that I cannot use key arrows, backspace, delete, ctrl+a, etc.

How can I limit it to only those keys that will give a string representation in the specific input?

Comment: Why don't you validate user input after it is submitted?

Comment: If you validate single chars, you may consider doing that on `keypress`. Also, it is better to use `test` rather than `match`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ignore those keys you need to add a condition before validating your input.

For example you can make an array containing the list of all KeyCodes that you want to ignore and just test if the typed key isn't one of them.

Here's what you need:

```js
document.getElementById('input-field').addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  //An array of special Keys
  var specialKeys = [37, 38, 39, 40, 8, 13, 27, 46];
  if (specialKeys.indexOf(e.which) === -1) {
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(e.which)+ ' Key is validated!');
    if (!String.fromCharCode(e.which).match(/[A-Za-z0-9,]/)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-field" placeholder="input text here">
```

**Note:**

As mentioned in comments you need to use `keypress`event instead of `keyup` to validate every inputted character immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is somehow to limit your input range. But I think in this case you are looking for a way to identify only printable key events.

You can achieve this by using the solution proposed by @TimDown on [How to detect if the pressed key will produce a character inside an `<input>` text-box?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4180715/4488121) applied to a `keypress` event as you can see on the code below. So then, you can work just with printable key events.

```js
    function isCharacterKeyPress(evt) {
        if (typeof evt.which == "undefined") {
            // This is IE, which only fires keypress events for printable keys
            return true;
        } else if (typeof evt.which == "number" && evt.which > 0) {
            // In other browsers except old versions of WebKit, evt.which is
            // only greater than zero if the keypress is a printable key.
            // We need to filter out backspace and ctrl/alt/meta key combinations
            return !evt.ctrlKey && !evt.metaKey && !evt.altKey && evt.which != 8;
        }
        return false;
    }

    document.getElementById('input-field').addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
     if(isCharacterKeyPress(e)){
            if (!String.fromCharCode(e.which).match(/[A-Za-z0-9,]/)) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-field" placeholder="input text here">
```